# Need to have an information regarding Virtual Ram of Macbook Which consists of Intel i5

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery, intel

0

I am facing an issue at my end which I am unable to get any resolution on the web and want to have a certain discussion on that and my problem is that. I want to have retrieve value of VRAM in recovery mode of MacBook pro which consists of intel i5 chip. When I am running "ioreg -l | grep VRAM,totalMB" this command on the terminal it's output is :- VRAM , totalMB = <0006000000000000> VRAM ,totalMB = 1536,

Now, When I am running the above command inside my recovery terminal of MacBook it's not showing the desired output which is generated on the normal terminal of my MacBook and my current requirement is the below mentioned output on the recovery mode. ( VRAM , totalMB = <0006000000000000>

VRAM ,totalMB = 1536) , So if there is any other command for this output then please provide that or if we can get it through this command then please redirect me to this issue.

I tried this in normal mode of MacBook consisting of intel chip. "ioreg -l | grep VRAM,totalMB" and the desired ouput is:- VRAM , totalMB = <0006000000000000> VRAM ,totalMB = 1536,

Now, inside the recovery mode the same above command in giving the single output which is :- VRAM , totalMB = <0006000000000000> and my requirement is to get both outputs on recovery mode as well or at least totalMB = 1536.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What VRAM information are you trying to get, and why? Which model of Mac is this? If it's one with Intel integrated graphics, then 1536 Mb is about the total that macOS will assign to it. Is thee a problem that you're trying to solve?